# SymPy and square roots of complex numbers

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When using `solve` to compute the roots of a quadratic equation, SymPy returns expressions which could be simplified but I can't get it to simplify them.  A minimal example looks like so:

```
from sympy import *
sqrt(-24-70*I)
```

Here, SymPy just returns `sqrt(-24-70*I)` while Mathematica or Maple will answer with the equivalent of `5-7*I`.

I'm aware that there are two square roots, but this behavior entails that SymPy will, for example, return pretty complicated solutions from

```
z = symbols("z")
solve(z ** 2 + (1 + I) * z + (6 + 18 * I), z)
```

while, again, Maple and Mathematica will both happily give me the two Gaussian integers that solve this equation.

Is there an option or something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the square root of z is logically the same as solving the equation (x+I*y)**2 = z. So you can do just that:

```
from sympy import *
z = -24-70*I
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
result = solve((x+I*y)**2 - z, (x, y))
```

The result is `[(-5, 7), (5, -7)]`

For convenience, this can be wrapped as a function:

```
def my_sqrt(z):
    x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
    sol = solve((x+I*y)**2 - z, (x, y))
    return sol[0][0] + sol[0][1]*I
```

Now you can use `my_sqrt(-24-70*I)` and get `-5 + 7*I`

---

The same strategy helps in your example with a quadratic equation:

```
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
z = x + I*y
solve(z ** 2 + (1 + I) * z + (6 + 18 * I), (x, y))
```

Output: `[(-3, 3), (2, -4)]`

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to use:

```
sqrt(-24-70*I).as_real_imag()
```

This returns the real and imaginary parts in a list, that can further be processed to recover a complex number.

Strange, though, that there is no built-in way of demanding the evaluation of the complex square root.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [mpmath](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/mpmath/basics.html) package, you can do something like

```
from sympy import *
import mpmath

a = -24-70*I
b = mpmath.mpc(re(a), im(a))  # a as mpmath.mpc object
c = mpmath.sqrt(b)
d = simplify(c)  # Convert back to sympy object
print(d)  # 5.0 - 7.0*I
```

Note that there may be a cheaper way (than `simplify`) to do the conversion back to a sympy object.

#### Update

As pointed out in the comments, this performs numeric evaluation, not symbolic. That is, the above is not really superior to this:

```
import cmath
result = cmath.sqrt(-24 - 70j)
print(result)  # 5 - 7j
```

The above have two interesting aspects. First, the `cmath` module is part of the standard library. Secondly, since `result` is given in terms of integers, we are guaranteed that `result` is actually the exact symbolic value (and it can easily be converted to a sympy object). If the solution is non-integer, the `result` is expressed as floats. This is of course not a general good solution to the problem of symbolic complex square roots, but it is useful if you know beforehand that the solution is integer.

Comment: It should be noted that this performs floating-point evaluation, not symbolic simplification. Simple `N(sqrt(-24-70*I))` would do the same without going through mpmath; but I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.  But as @zaq already guessed, I was interested in an exact solution.