# How do I tell sympy that i^2 = -1?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm currently using sympy to check my algebra on some nasty equations involving second order derivatives and complex numbers.

```py
import sympy
from sympy.abc import a, e, i, h, t, x, m, A

# define a wavefunction
Psi = A * sympy.exp(-a * ((m*x**2 /h)+i*t))

# take the first order time derivative
Psi_dt = sympy.diff(Psi, t)
# take the second order space derivative
Psi_d2x = sympy.diff(Psi, x, 2)

# write an expression for energy potential (rearrange Schrodingers Equation)
V = 1/Psi * (i*h*Psi_dt + (((h**2)/2*m) * Psi_d2x))


# symplify potential function
sympy.simplify(V)
```

Which yields this nice thing:

`a*(-h*i**2 + m**2*(2*a*m*x**2 - h))`

It would be really nice if sympy simplified i^2 to -1.
So how do I tell it that `i` represents the square root of -1?

On a related note, it would also be really nice to tell sympy that `e` is eulers number, so if I call `sympy.diff(e**x, x)` I get `e**x` as output.

Comment: I think you might want to use the big `I`. This question also might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386963/sympy-imaginary-number

Comment: Huh, I seam to have overlooked the big I first time I checked that. Thanks, though seams like I also got the answer I needed in the interim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SymPy Imaginary Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386963/sympy-imaginary-number)

Comment: Indirectly, yes, but it was not immediatly apparent that `I` (the sqrt of -1) and `E` (eulers number) were builtins of sympy, as was pointed out below by @Prune

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the SymPy [built-ins](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html), rather than treating those symbols as free variables.  In particular:

```
from sympy import I, E
```

`I` is sqrt(-1); `E` is Euler's number.

Then use the `complexes` methods to manipulate the complex numbers as needed.

Comment: in this particular example, would I need `complexes`? I took your suggestion and imported `I as i`, then changed nothing else in my code and got what looks like the same result except the first term is +ve and the `i` disappeared (as I would have liked)

Comment: You do not need `complexes` in this example alone -- only if you have other manipulation to do, such as extracting the real and imaginary components.